# separating 2 words from a string

Tags: c++

I have done a lot of reading on this topic online, and cannot figure out if my code is working.  i am working on my phone with the c4droid  app, and the debugger is nearly useless as far as i can tell.
as the title says, i need to separate 2 words out of one input. depending on  what the first word is, the second may or may not be used.  if i do not need the second word everything is fine. if i need and have the second word it works, or seems to.  but if i need a second word but only have the first it compiles, but crashes with an out of range exception.
ActionCommand is a vector of strings with 2 elements.

```
void splitstring(std::string original)
{
    std::string
    std::istringstream OrigStream(original);
    OrigStream >> x;
    ActionCommand.at(0) = x;
    OrigStream >> x;
    ActionCommand.at(1) = x;
    return;
}
```

this code will separate the words right?
any help would be appreciated.

more of the code:
called from main-

```
void DoAction(Character & Player, room & RoomPlayerIn)
{
    ParseAction(Player, GetAction(), RoomPlayerIn);
return;
}

std::string GetAction()
{
    std::string action;
    std::cout<< ">";
    std::cin>>action;
    action = Lowercase(action);
    return action;
}
```

maybe Lowercase is the problem.

```
std::string Lowercase(std::string sourceString)
{
    std::string destinationString;
    destinationString.resize(sourceString.size());

    std::transform(sourceString.begin(), sourceString.end(), destinationString.begin(), ::tolower);

    return destinationString;
)



void ParseAction(Character & Player, std::string CommandIn, room & RoomPlayerIn)
(
    std::vector<std::string> ActionCommand;
    splitstring(CommandIn, ActionCommand);
    std::string action = ActionCommand.at(0);
    if (ActionCommand.size() >1)
       std::string action2 = ActionCommand.at(1);
```

skipping some ifs

```
    if (action =="wield")
    {
      if(ActionCommand.size() >1)  
         DoWield(action2);
      else std::cout<<"wield what??"<<std::endl;
      return;
    }
```

and splitstring now looks like this

```
void splitstring(std::string const &original, std::vector<std::string> &ActionCommand)
{
    std::string x;
    std::istringstream OrigStream(original);
    if (OrigStream >>x)
       ActionCommand.push_back(x);
    else return;
    if (OrigStream>>x)
       ActionCommand.push_back(x);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is ActionCommand?

Comment: its a std::vector<std::string>

Comment: Why do you use global variables?

Comment: primarily because i couldnt get a vector of classes to pass into a function without 8 pages of errors. couldnt find out why after many google searches, so i worked around it.  and just avoided it here.

Comment: pass it as a reference: `void splitstring(std::string const &original, std::vector<std::string> &ActionCommand)` and avoid global variables!

Comment: thanks. ill be going back to it again, see if i have any better luck.

Comment: ive removed this global variable successfully.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> ActionCommand;

void splitstring(std::string const &original)
{
    std::string x;
    std::istringstream OrigStream{ original };
    if(OrigStream >> x)
        ActionCommand.push_back(x);
    else return;

    if(OrigStream >> x)
        ActionCommand.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: aha. avoid reading the second one at all if its not there. should have thought of that. thanks!

Comment: i am now having a problem with this that i cant figure out.  it is never doing the second push_back.  instead it is treating the second word as a whole new input. effectively i can do two commamds at once, and they are processed in sequence, separately. ideas?

Comment: If there are > 2 sequences of printable characters in `original` the above code \*will\* read 2 of them and push them in the vector `ActionCommand`. If your result is different you are using different code of input for what was said isn't true.

Comment: I have added more code to the original post.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to use the standard library. You can split a string into tokens (using spaces as dividers) with the following function:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

inline auto tokenize(const std::string &String)
{
    auto Stream = std::stringstream(String);
    return std::vector<std::string>{std::istream_iterator<std::string>{Stream}, std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}};
}
```

Here, the result is created in place by using an `std::istream_iterator`, which basically stands in for the `>>` operation in your example.

**Warning:**
This code needs at least c++11 to compile.

Comment: i have read this answer a dozen times. and ive seen similar answers in similar questions and threads

Comment: for some reason i cant follow it. ill come back to it another time. that usually works for me. thank you for the answer.

Comment: I have to say, the mechanisms is a bit tricky indeed! You should check out, what  [braced initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) does, and have a look at the possible constructors for [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (you need the 7). This line basically tells the vector to copy from another vector (which is faked with the `std::istream_iterator`) . Furthermore, you have to tell the compiler how to initialize new values, which is done with the second part.

Comment: @jan.sende: "Furthermore, you have to tell the compiler how to initialize new values, which is done with the second part." What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Swordfish I had another look and noticed that I made a mistake. What you actually need is constructor 4! You are creating a vector by using a set of iterators. With `std::istream_iterator<std::string>{Stream}` being the start and `std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}` the end iterator. The braced initializer syntax helps with performance...

Comment: @jan.sende: That sounds better. "The braced initializer syntax helps with performance..." is a long shot, though.